# How to concatenate the first row of a sheet into a list separated by commas?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate the first row of a sheet into a list separated by commas. It is throwing the type mismatch error.

All values in the cells are strings and there is a value in every cell.

I have tried declaring headers to a variant as well.

```
lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
headers = Join(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lc)), ",")

Debug.Print headers
```

Comment: You're tying to pass a 2-dimensional array to Join - try passing the range's value through Application.Transpose to convert it to something Join can process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't join a `Range`, you join a 1-dimensional array. What's implicit here, is a call to `Range.Value`, which, because the range contains multiple cells, is going to be a 2D variant array: you need to pass it to `Application.Transpose` once to turn it into a one-dimensional array, and once more to make it vertical so that the `VBA.Strings.Join` function will be able to work with.

Also, watch out for [implicit ActiveSheet references](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference): unless that code is written in a worksheet module (where the implicit qualifier would be `Me.`), all these unqualified `Range` and `Cells` member calls are implicitly working off whatever the `ActiveSheet` is.

```
With ActiveSheet
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    Dim headerCells As Variant
    headerCells = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lc)).Value '2D variant array
End With

Dim headers As String
headers = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(headerCells)), ",")

Debug.Print headers
```

Comment: This code is throwing an invalid procedure/call error. I tried to use it with WorksheetFunction.Transpose also.

Comment: @gerpes8 that's because the array needs to be transposed twice, because we're looking at a horizontal layout.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon your answer line `once to turn it into a one-dimensional array, and once more to make it vertical so that the VBA.Strings.Join function will be able to work with.` . I am bit confused about the portion make it vertical. should not it be horizental or vertical is correct .

Comment: Another possible way: `Join(Application.Index(headerCells, 1, 0), ",")`

Comment: @JvdV oooh that's clever, love it!